# Communicating between classes java

Tags: java, swing

I have a class called `myJPanel1`, in which I've created an instance of the class `Student`. I've also created a button in `myJPanel1` that displays info about this new student. When I click on that button, I want to change the text of a button in a separate `JPanel`, written in class called `myJPanel2`.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the `myJPanel1` to recognize the buttons in `myJPanel2` so I can modify the button's text.

**myJPanel1:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class myJPanel1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public myJPanel1() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.yellow);

        Student st1 = new Student("John", "Lodger", 44);
        // the whatsUp of this student has to shown in the other panel

        JButton j11 = new JButton(st1.getInfo());
        j11.addActionListener(this);
        add(j11);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Event) {
        Object obj = Event.getSource();

        if (obj == j11) {
            j2.setText(st1.whatsUp());
        }
    }  
}
```

**myJPanel2:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class myJPanel2 extends JPanel {

    public myJPanel2() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.pink);
        //setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        JButton j1 = new JButton("When the user clicks on the button in the UPPER panel");
        add(j1);

        JButton j2 = new JButton("Display here whatsUp from the student in UPPER Panel");
        add(j2);

        JButton j3 = new JButton("===>>>>You CANNOT create a student here <======");
        add(j3);

        JButton j4 = new JButton("It has to be the student from the UPPER Panel");
        add(j4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to establish some kind of contract that allows `myJPanel1` to change the state of `myJPanel2` without exposing parts of either components to misuse.

For example, `myJPanel1` shouldn't care what `myJPanel2` wants to do with the informaiton, only that it can provide the information to it.

You could establish a model which provided the ability to change various properties and provide appropriate change notification to interested parties or your could simply provide a method in `myJPanel2` which allows `myJPanel1` to supply the information you need.

For example...

```
public class myJPanel2 extends JPanel {
    // You'll want to use these beyond the scope of the
    // constructor
    private JButton j1;
    private JButton j2;
    private JButton j3
    private JButton j4;
    public myJPanel2() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.pink);
        //setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        j1 = new JButton("When the user clicks on the button in the UPPER panel");
        add(j1);

        j2 = new JButton("Display here whatsUp from the student in UPPER Panel");
        add(j2);

        j3 = new JButton("===>>>>You CANNOT create a student here <======");
        add(j3);

        j4 = new JButton("It has to be the student from the UPPER Panel");
        add(j4);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        j2.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Then in you `actionPerformed` method, you would simply take the active reference to `myJPanel2` and call it's `setText` method, for example...

```
public class myJPanel1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private myJPanel2 panel2;

    public myJPanel1() {
        super();
        //...
        panel2 = new MyJPanel2();
        add(panel2);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Event) {
        Object obj = Event.getSource();

        if (obj == j11) {
            panel2.setText(st1.whatsUp());
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you don't have any reference to the buttons, You create them and assign them to a temporary reference that when the constructor is finishing it's job `j1` will not have any alive variable to hold them.

You should move the buttons into your `JPanel` class.

**Example:**

```
public class myJPanel2 extends JPanel {

    public JButton j1;

    public myJPanel2() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.pink);
        //setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        j1 = new JButton("When the user clicks on the button in the UPPER panel");
        add(j1);
        ....
    }
}
```

**Comment:** Same goes for `myJPanel1` if you want to use it's buttons all over the class.

Comment: Exposing instance variables publicity is bad design and expose too much of class to inappropriate misuse by outside source (I can do nasty things to your button and child components)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Can't agree more, but I can't give him the whole "Access modifiers" bible on one foot. So I gave him a taste, and the rest is up to him.